# Is DTO-Endpoint validation not moving the business logic to a wrong layer?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In asp.net web api model validation is done with DataAnnotations or FluentValidation framework.

According to MS validation is done: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

This is a sample from the above link:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 999)]
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Microsoft seems to use for simple samples a mix of a DTO/Business Model/Persistance object... terrible... It's passed to the client and database the same time.

**Question**: Stuff like the Weight must between 0 and 999 does this not belong to the service layer instead of the application layer?

For me this is business logic as there is no database limitation for this field type (double) so its for sure no dataprovider logic.

Comment: In situations such as this I would make a copy of each domain object or dto into the corresponding app specific class that you have pointed out above. Then use tools like automapper to.map back and fourth from your domain object. The domain objects remain annotation free while the Clint facing facades can take advantage of localization strings, validations, constraints ect.

Comment: I am not talking about automapper or mapping objects.

Comment: The annotations are useful in mvc for built in client validations. Not so much in web API. Since web API and mvc frameworks will be merged in mvc6, remove any you dont wish to use. I localize the display labels of properties at the model layer and find it useful and none of that is in my service/data layer.

Comment: When you do NOT use EF code-first, rather database first where do you put the StringLength(25,...)-Attribute that only 25 chars should get into your database field? On the entity I guess not DTO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Stuff like the Weight must between 0 and 999 does this not belong to
>   the service layer instead of the application layer?

Model validation shouldn't necessarily be *domain*.

For example, ASP.NET WebAPI uses model validation to actually perform HTTP entity validation. This is a valuable validation because it means that an unexpected HTTP request may not reach an API controller and this is nice because you avoid executing a lot of code before doing actual *domain* logic.

Since data annotations and model validation are a cross-layer feature, you can both validate DTOs and domain models using same data annotation attributes and validator and you're not breaking a good separation of concerns.

For me, DTO validation is more like a *contract*: *I won't process a request where it's data isn't in the form I'm expecting it*. I'm not goint to implement a deep validation, but at least I receive the required data in the expected format.

At the end of the day, you need to decide the right validation rules that are applied to your software layers. Maybe DTOs shouldn't validate that a weight should be between 0 and 999 but it should check that weight is equal or greater than 0, while domain layer should validate against concrete domain rules/specifications. If some domain requires that a weight should be less than 999, add this validation there. **Any domain receiving data from the DTO won't be receiving negative weights, while a domain may validate if it's between 0 and 999.**

Comment: @Sub-Zero Yes, BTW, it's necessary or the domain couldn't be validated if it's not consumed by the layer that has validation already

Comment: What if we don't add validation on the domain models? if you use DTO for all inputs, Domain models wouldn't need validation at any point

Comment: @HosseinShahdoost Until these domain models are consumed by the its domain or others :/

Comment: Good point, But It's a matter of responsibility, if we take the responsibility of validation from our domain we don't have to go through all this. We just need to know that we have to feed the domain with validated models. (sorry about the delay)